# "Overwriting" Linked Lists in C

Tags: c, sorting, memory, linked-list, free

Premise:
One of the required functions in the assignment is to sort a linked list. The way I've done it is probably very inefficient, but its the only way I know how to do it.

Question:
If I have one linked list of information, how would I (within a function) "overwrite" the information of a passed in linked list.

Code:

```
void sortPlaylist(Node **pList) {
    Node * pCur = (*pList);

    // Find size of list
    int size = sizeOfList(*pList);

    // Create a new Node, allocate the memory for a copy of the whole list
    Node * sortedList = NULL;

    // Create an array of the Records in our list
    Record * records;
    records = malloc(size * sizeof(Record));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        records[i] = pCur->record;
        pCur = pCur->pNext;
    }

    // Selection sort the records (it works with arrays, the code is long though)

    // Write the sorted records into a new list
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("\nAdding artist to new list %s\n\n", records[i].artist);
        insertFront(&sortedList, records[i]);
        printRecord(sortedList);
    }

    // ERROR HERE I THINK
    // Assign the sorted list to pList
    *pList = sortedList;

    // Free the sortedList
    free(sortedList);
}
```

The error is with how I'm assigning the sorted list back to the original pList I believe. Also I'd like to know if the use of free(sortedList) is correct there and it will free up all the memory involved in the sortedList, or just the pointer to it, in which case I think I just run through a for loop freeing up the whole list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `free(sortedList)` call is definitely a problem.  You have created a whole linked list,
set `pList` to point to it, and then deleted the head.

It's more likely that you want to free the nodes in the original list, since you are going to give the caller the copies of them in the new `sortedList`.

Also, yes, in order not to leak memory, you need to walk the list and free each node. (Assuming `insertFront` is creating new nodes).

Comment: Another option would be to run through sortedList and the original pList simultaneously, and copy values from one to the other.   Then you could free sortedList as you go.     A better option might be to avoid the copy entirely and reimplement the sort algorithm to work on lists instead of arrays.

Comment: I think Ill go with the second option. Thanks